# Converting generic Set to generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm currently working on an assignment with a number of methods with parameters of type Set. In order to use these parameters in my program they have to be converted to arrays, and the conversion has to be done with time complexity no greater than O(N). I'm stumped, as I don't know the type of the set, or any properties at all about it. I can get the size of the set, but that's about it. I am not allowed to use ArrayList, or any other List or Set class. toArray() doesn't work, the compiler says it can't find the symbol. I obviously can't create a generic type array. What do I do now?

Here's a sample of the code. there are 6 more methods with headers similar to it.

```
   public boolean equals(Set<T> s) {
  T[] sArray = s.toArray(new T[s.size()]);
```

My error messages are as follows:

```
ArraySet.java:241: error: generic array creation
  T[] sArray = s.toArray(new T[s.size()]);
                         ^
ArraySet.java:241: error: cannot find symbol
      T[] sArray = s.toArray(new T[s.size()]);
                    ^
  symbol:   method toArray(T[])
  location: variable s of type Set<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in class ArraySet
```

Comment: please add the complete error message and the code you have so far.

Comment: Have you tried `set.toArray(T[] array)`? This could work for you if you don't care for the actual type

Comment: The problem with that is Java won't allow me to create a generic array.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the `Set` into an `array` for an `equals()` method?

Comment: This conversion is needed for a lot more than just the equals() method. It is also needed to find the union, intersection, and complement of a given Set and an array, where the result must be returned as a Set in ascending natural order. To maintain that order I need access to the elements in the Set, and to do that I need it in an Array. I am not allowed to use any other Set or List implementation, so no ArrayList or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: Updated so that ArraySet actually behaves like a Set...*

Here's an example of how you could implement your `equals(Set<T> s)` method. Since not of all `ArraySet` was included in your question, I've had to assume how your `ArraySet` will work, and that it supports any reference type (generics).

The `equal(Set<T> s)` method, simply loops through the array and uses the `contains(Object o)` method on `s`. This is O(n) since worst case scenario you loop through all n element of the array. It will continue checking until it finds that it doesn't contain an element or all elements have been checked. Note that the loop won't start if the `size()` of the `Set` and the `length` of the array are not equal.

```
import java.util.Set;

public class ArraySet<T> {

    private T[] array;
    private int count;

    private final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 16;

    public ArraySet() {
        array = (T[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        count = 0;
    }

    public void add(T e) {
        if (count < array.length && !contains(e)) {
            array[count++] = e;
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(T e) {
        boolean hasElement = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (!hasElement && i < count) {
            hasElement = array[i++].equals(e);
        }
        return hasElement;
    }

    public boolean equals(Set<T> s) {
        boolean isEqual = s.size() == count;
        int i = 0;
        while (isEqual && i < count) {
            isEqual = s.contains(array[i++]);
        }
        return isEqual;
    }

}
```

Example of using `ArraySet`'s `equals(Set<T> s)` method:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ArraySetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
        stringSet.add("Foo1");
        stringSet.add("Foo2");

        ArraySet<String> arraySet = new ArraySet<>();
        arraySet.add("Foo1");
        arraySet.add("Foo2");

        System.out.println(arraySet.equals(stringSet));

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have any idea what the type of the Set is, it's generic. I am not permitted to use any other implementation of any Set or List, or any of their subclasses.

Comment: So are you implementing your own version of a Set? The question really isn't very clear, at least to me. You have put the example of a method `equals` and the class given the error is `ArraySet` which leads me to my assumption.

Comment: Yes, this whole thing is a custom implementation of a Set.

Comment: @GrahamMcclelland I've updated the answer, hopefully it addresses your question.

Comment: @GrahamMcclelland re-updated so that `ArraySet` behaves as expected when adding...

Comment: But say both sets contain 2 elements which are the same, and the others are not the same. The possibility exists that it could correctly catch that one of the elements is not the same, but if you then encounter an element which is the same between sets the isEqual value would be set back to true, yes?

Comment: No as the while loop will terminate once it identifies that an element is not in the other set.